# show data in table view in android

Tags: android

I want to get data from `database` in my android `table view`.

Should I use loop? Is static good for this?

Comment: what do you mean by "static"?

Comment: TextView value3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.value3);
                     value3.setText(k2); that kind of code.. meance statical is neccessary?

Comment: @WarrenFaith: i think by static he means without using any loop. Manually setting values in textbox.

Comment: If you want a table view to render tabular data, you can look at http://www.androidjetpack.com/Home/AndroidDataGrid

Comment: https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from message");               

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (rs1.next())
            {
                String script = rs1.getString(1);
                String call =  rs1.getString(2);
                String price =  rs1.getString(3);
                String stoploss =  rs1.getString(4);
                String target =  rs1.getString(5);
                String ltp =  rs1.getString(6);
                String exit =  rs1.getString(7);
                sb.append(script).append(";").append(call).append(";").append(price).append(";").append(stoploss).append(";").append(target).append(";").append(ltp).append(";").append(exit).append("_");
            }
            out.print(sb.toString());
            out.flush();
```

for this you have XML
for this you have a XML like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="20dip">  
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tab"       
    >
      <TableRow>        
      </TableRow>    
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

to show the data in the android you write.

```
        String st = new String(str);    
        Log.e("Main",st);
        String[] rows  = st.split("_");
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();


        for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            String row  = rows[i];
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            final String[] cols = row.split(";");

            Handler handler = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

                final String col = cols[j];                                 
                final TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));                              
                tableRow.addView(columsView);
```

Answer (score 12):

This may be useful for you..

```
try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    int flag=1;

    // when i=-1, loop will display heading of each column
    // then usually data will be display from i=0 to jArray.length()
    for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length();i++){

        TableRow tr=new TableRow(Yourclassname.this);

        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // this will be executed once
        if(flag==1){

            TextView b3=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b3.setText("column heading 1");
            b3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            b3.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b3);

            TextView b4=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b4.setTextSize(15);
            b4.setText("column heading 2");
            b4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tr.addView(b4);

            TextView b5=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b5.setText("column heading 3");
            b5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            b5.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b5);
            tv.addView(tr);

            final View vline = new View(Yourclassname.this);
            vline.setLayoutParams(new       
            TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
            vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.addView(vline); // add line below heading
            flag=0;
        } else {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            TextView b=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            String str=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("column1"));
            b.setText(str);
            b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            b.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b);

            TextView b1=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b1.setTextSize(15);
            String str1=json_data.getString("column2");
            b1.setText(str1);
            b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr.addView(b1);

            TextView b2=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            String str2=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("column3"));
            b2.setText(str2);
            b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            b2.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b2);
            tv.addView(tr);
            final View vline1 = new View(Yourclassname.this);
            vline1.setLayoutParams(new                
            TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
            vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.addView(vline1);  // add line below each row   
        }
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` is deprecated; use `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: Is it necessary to allocate a new View for a newline on each row item? Can we not re-use the same one?

Comment: @JamesWierzba yeah, you can use the same view. Define the view outside for loop.

Answer (score 9):

I see this post is pretty old, but if someone else is facing also the issue to display custom data in a Table in Android, I would like to offer my [TableView](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView) as possible solution to do so.
So you do not care about how to fill the data to your table, you can simply create a **custom adapter** for the data you want to show (like we already know in Android from views like the ListView).

our code will look like this:

```
List<Flight> myData = new ArrayList<>();
myData.add(new Flight(...));
myData.add(new Flight(...));
myData.add(new Flight(...));

TableView<Flight> table = findViewById(R.id.table);
table.setHeaderAdapter(new SimpleHeaderAdapter("Time", "Airline", "Flight", "Destination"));
table.setDataAdapter(new FlightDataAdapter(myData));
```

The result could look like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: Its best library for table solution in Android. You should maintain it regularly.

Answer (score 4):

That depends. If you're sure that you'll have only a few rows then you can inflate add them in loop to the TableLayout. But note that you create view for every row.

With lot of data create ListView and adapter for example based on CursorAdapter:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private static final String TAG                = "MyCursorAdapter";
private final int           NAME_COLUMN;
private final int           ADDRESS_COLUMN;
private final int           STATE_COLUMN;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    NAME_COLUMN        = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
    ADDRESS_COLUMN     = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View                view     = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);

    MyRowViewHolder rowData  = new MyRowViewHolder();

    rowData.name                 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    rowData.address              = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);

    rowData.name.setText(cursor.getString(NAME_COLUMN));
    rowData.address.setText(cursor.getString(ADDRESS_COLUMN));

    view.setTag(rowData);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    MyRowViewHolder rowData = (MyRowViewHolder) view.getTag();
    rowData.name.setText(cursor.getString(NAME_COLUMN));
    rowData.address.setText(cursor.getString(ADDRESS_COLUMN));
}

public static class MyRowViewHolder {
    TextView  name;
    TextView  address;
}
}
```

This approach doesn't create view for every row. I think that's better but needs more effort. To get table layout style use LinearLayout for rows with layout_weight for columns

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To the ListView add header and footer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Static can be used when you have a defined never changing number of rows/cols in your table you want to fill. Otherwise I suggest to use a loop and add a row to the table view for each step in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

We could imagine a custom component for android : the TableView.

Its code would be something like :

```
public class TableView extends TableLayout {

    public TableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setAdapter(TableAdapter<?> adapter) {
        removeAllViews();

        for (int row = 0; row < adapter.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
            TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(params);
            addView(tableRow);
            for (int column = 0; column < adapter.getColumnCount(); column++) {
                View cell = adapter.getView(row, column);
                tableRow.addView(cell);
                TableRow.LayoutParams cellParams = (android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams) cell.getLayoutParams();
                cellParams.weight = adapter.getColumnWeight(column);
                                    cellParams.width = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it would use an adapter like this :

```
public interface TableAdapter<T> {
    int getRowCount();

    int getColumnWeight(int column);

    int getColumnCount();

    T getItem(int row, int column);

    View getView(int row, int column);
}
```

Comment: If you want that, see the [TableView](https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView) library for Android.