# Tableview in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [show data in table view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968226/show-data-in-table-view-in-android)

how to data set in tableview.
how to show data in tableview.

Comment: I assume you're talking about TableLayout?

Answer (score 4):

A quick example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                TextView text = new TextView(this);
                text.setLayoutParams(params);
                text.setText(String.format("(%d, %d)", i, j));
                row.addView(text);
            }
            table.addView(row);
        }
        setContentView(table);
    }
}
```

If you can get away with it, [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) can be much easier to work with using adapters such as [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).