# database display in android

Tags: android

I want to display a table from database with 5 columns with various string length.Which is the best way to display that.Thanks i advance.Previously i tried with listview but various string length shows rows not coming correctly.

My layout.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">           

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"          
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text5"          
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text7"          
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text9"          
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.report);            
String[] from;
int[] to;
db.open();          
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);     
Cursor c = db.getEducationTitle();

while(c. moveToNext())
{
    // Cursor c = db.getEducationTitle();
    LinearLayout linearlayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
    TextView edt=(TextView) new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    edt.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col1"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col2"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col3"))+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col4"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col5")));
    linearlayout.addView(edt);

}
```

Comment: read it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968226/show-data-in-table-view-in-android

Comment: dynamic table layout is your best bet. check this [tutorial](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/dynamic-tablelayout-in-android/).

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
 SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("databasename", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    LinearLayout linearlayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

       while(cursor.moveToNext)
        {

                TextView edt=(TextView) new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                edt.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col1"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col2"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col3"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col4"))+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("col5")));
                linearlayout.addView(edt);

        }
```

Comment: you must add an id to linearlayout

Comment: you must add an id to linearlayout

Comment: did you change the name of the database name and the table name?

Comment: As i posted in my code..In dbhelper class i have Cursor c = db.getEducationTitle();
Which will give me the data i wanted and displaying that.Is there any need to change to name??

Comment: after c=db.getEducationTitle() put a log.d and see if there is any data in the cursor

Comment: and replace the col1,col2... with the colomn name you specified in your db

Comment: jaisonDavis i tried for both.I printed the count of this line Cursor c = db.getEducationTitle();
It shows exact count in database,so data is there.Next i replaced column,no result.