# Android - can't see row in tablelayout

Tags: android, xml, layout

This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/MainTable"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code

```
     private void showMarkets () {

    markets = marketAdapter.getAllMarkets();

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    //TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

    newRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
    newRow.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    for (int i = 0; i < marketAdapter.headingTitle.length; i++){
        newRow.addView(createView(marketAdapter.headingTitle[i], 20, android.R.color.white));
        Log.e("title", marketAdapter.headingTitle[i]);
    }

    table.addView(newRow);
}
public TextView createView (String columnName, int size, int columnColor)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText(columnName);
        textView.setTextSize(size);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(columnColor));
        textView.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        return textView;
    }
```

## tried a lot of example in the internet but nothing works well , I wonder where is my problem and im really sorry for my bad English I hope that u can help me

add my create view function

Comment: ScrollView should be the parent element. You don't need the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Why are you adding TableRows programatically?

Comment: to insert data from table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968226/show-data-in-table-view-in-android

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView should be the parent element. You don't need the relative layout. Try this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainTable"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="TextView in a row"/>
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Did you put something in your TableLayout or is it empty?

Comment: In that case, ofcourse nothing will show. Add some TableRows with some Widgets inside :)

Comment: look at this line newRow.addView(createView(marketAdapter.headingTitle[i], 20, android.R.color.white));

Comment: create view return a textview

Comment: Add this line in createView: `textview.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set layout parameters to the new row:

```
  private void showMarkets () {

    markets = marketAdapter.getAllMarkets();

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    //TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

    newRow.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
    newRow.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    for (int i = 0; i < marketAdapter.headingTitle.length; i++){

    //add layout params to view inside layout row as well
        newRow.addView(createView(marketAdapter.headingTitle[i], 20, android.R.color.white),new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
        Log.e("title", marketAdapter.headingTitle[i]);
    }
    newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    table.addView(newRow);
}
```

Comment: still the same problem